# How can I implement a grid system in my div using CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I want to create a div with 2 columns, when I add an item in my parent div it should be in the first column, when the first column has 3 elements and I want to add a other item it should be in the second column.
This is an image of what I'm looking for :
[image]

I did not find a response in internet,I've tried css grid generator but nothing..

Css grid generator but I can't have a correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do in html is:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">1</div>
   <div class="child">2</div>
   <div class="child">3</div>
   <div class="child">4</div>
   <div class="child">5</div>
   <div class="child">6</div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.parent{
     display:grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
     grid-auto-flow: column;
     grid-template-rows:1fr 1fr 1fr;
 }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2aL06qvw/2/)

Comment: Your demo display 135 in first column and 246 in the second one, I want 123 and 456 instead

Comment: Can you check again, sorry i forgot to change the link

Comment: Wohouuuuu great thank you, have you any gcss grid link for me please ?

Comment: You can check [this](https://youtu.be/rg7Fvvl3taU)

Comment: Why the size of my div is unchangeable ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rgd9j3o0/12/ I want to keep grid system but with differents size types..

Answer (score 0):

Ok... It looks like you just have the problem of grid flow. To change it use `grid-auto-flow: column;` That's it and the flow of your grid will change from rows to columns. You can change the `grid-template-rows` according to your desire.

Comment: What can I change in gentbrika's answer ?